# How to plot two sets of data with a Filling such that the fillings' intersection doesn't change color?

Tags: plotting

Consider two sets of data, `data1` and `data2` (they are given below). If I try to plot them,

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, data2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Blue}}, Joined -> True, Filling -> Automatic]
```

I will obtain something like this: [image]

Is there any way to plot them in a way such that the area of their intersection will be the same color as the areas where they are not intersected? Likely without arbitrary opacity.

```
data1={{0.2999999847368421, 0.00007847597621237087}, {0.2999999847368421, 
  0.000041788092286919155}, {0.2999999847368421, 
  0.000022251964757397896}, {0.2999999847368421, 
  0.0000220678601151695}, {0.2999086890022088, 
  0.00002208484265800435}, {0.299135470025212, 
  0.000022251964757397896}, {0.29305964572645016, 
  0.000023559042135848565}, {0.2923684065927977, 
  0.000023715417699775446}, {0.29149457598987855, 
  0.00002391694676035076}, {0.28622923423326985, 
  0.000025170342352025765}, {0.2847368284487534, 
  0.000025544864044561507}, {0.28283824980403144, 
  0.00002602887044236093}, {0.27941745452266786, 
  0.00002693325175144503}, {0.2771052503047091, 
  0.000027574767347538766}, {0.27414093369651227, 
  0.00002842332559813959}, {0.27262803295115967, 
  0.00002887289075546239}, {0.26947367216066476, 
  0.000029839338905920736}, {0.2674167233640278, 
  0.000030493723236879715}, {0.26585724316222964, 
  0.00003099987331245628}, {0.2653989013108051, 
  0.00003115287099495151}, {0.2618420940166204, 
  0.00003235951331170112}, {0.25910881151239357, 
  0.000033345050500262494}, {0.2566121526469104, 
  0.00003427085042641089}, {0.2542105158725761, 
  0.000035200684917703386}, {0.2523827380016514, 
  0.000035933924343589724}, {0.24776950863528088, 
  0.00003787531113975004}, {0.2465789377285318, 
  0.000038403409002727274}, {0.24567902263000313, 
  0.000038795354781778083}, {0.2427631486565096, 
  0.00004014331161385088}, {0.23939452236636505, 
  0.000041788092286919155}, {0.23900139175396434, 
  0.000041974956094407755}, {0.23894735958448746, 
  0.00004200725834238921}, {0.23887469563243233, 
  0.00004203958544888939}, {0.2323498453735351, 
  0.000045513079034589037}, {0.23131578144044312, 
  0.000046097997889804963}, {0.22991280821230217, 
  0.000046920871261138605}, {0.22572438348871537, 
  0.00004945584514987175}, {0.22368420329639882, 
  0.00005077423724654412}, {0.22088757273140602, 
  0.00005264359063778916}, {0.21912873245602082, 
  0.000053872622507582905}, {0.21605262515235452, 
  0.000056131722625208974}, {0.21256289227545141, 
  0.00005882848791880944}, {0.21178408376368124, 
  0.00005944718178346996}, {0.20842104700831018, 
  0.00006224574676266308}, {0.20602313659049157, 
  0.00006437877343232213}, {0.20259861495261233, 
  0.00006758604063277815}, {0.20078946886426585, 
  0.00006936639909688728}, {0.19950946540114126, 
  0.00007060462559901383}, {0.19419568100982915, 
  0.00007203099599317158}, {0.19315789072022155, 
  0.000070702457797849}, {0.1915089779620479, 
  0.00006848623690747524}, {0.1877043679595727, 
  0.0000655582201752986}, {0.18552631257617724, 
  0.00006502581900288756}, {0.18319547657564023, 
  0.00006473633752977752}, {0.18022929678918553, 
  0.0000647164208590649}, {0.1778947344321329, 
  0.00006579061639282816}, {0.1759588922222545, 
  0.00006688264196152569}, {0.17169966672487036, 
  0.000069698027991677}, {0.17026315628808858, 
  0.00007074598227692727}, {0.16915083886816806, 
  0.0000715890703672052}, {0.1628570227132409, 
  0.00007702856693563057}, {0.16263157814404428, 
  0.0000772540665362398}, {0.16246575527909798, 
  0.00007740873598046131}, {0.16137952235478703, 
  0.00007847597621237087}, {0.1559371786636851, 
  0.00008479024550498915}, {0.15499999999999997, 
  0.00008598570939586575}, {0.15363429033701548, 
  0.0000878443636223182}, {0.14952784545677286, 
  0.00009379466248802923}, {0.14736842185595564, 
  0.00009723293672220618}, {0.14409481765696008, 
  0.00010283357787557963}, {0.14320049209320487, 
  0.00010446007275761177}, {0.1397368437119113, 
  0.00011114188215085727}, {0.13695884492949673, 
  0.00011716452189394137}, {0.1342348783165591, 
  0.0001236085720280136}, {0.132105265567867, 
  0.00012901013630317747}, {0.13081408303519548, 
  0.00013246966302280202}, {0.1257555540652051, 
  0.00014737401267806525}, {0.12474012191469142, 
  0.00015065231188607817}, {0.12447368742382268, 
  0.00015155898228429117}, {0.12401348239414031, 
  0.00015308224162798693}, {0.11874814063753161, 
  0.00017249445411395565}, {0.11684210927977837, 
  0.0001805037702493432}, {0.11336355547242224, 
  0.00019641246454919555}, {0.11284559191674734, 
  0.0001989673011140506}, {0.10921053113573405, 
  0.00021817518248477453}, {0.10702874939582294, 
  0.0002311329610459566}, {0.10215840142987279, 
  0.00026383042098478994}, {0.10157895299168973, 
  0.0002681270934084663}, {0.10129388671824277, 
  0.00027032239338430433}, {0.10047595146305832, 
  0.00027676112692193297}, {0.09562982481445986, 
  0.0003180103296691775}, {0.09394737484764541, 
  0.0003344186780080345}, {0.09030113499708517, 
  0.00037399586047134474}, {0.09005519546705248, 
  0.0003768839705616018}, {0.08986328810649669, 
  0.000379268855541332}, {0.0863157967036011, 
  0.0004251992889145789}, {0.08458490410208322, 
  0.00045052187423797835}, {0.08046541697403586, 
  0.0005197437457472359}, {0.07922640343258337, 
  0.0005435420441421504}, {0.07868421855955678, 
  0.0005546081232062334}, {0.0772551608358063, 
  0.0005848415758826891}, {0.07400205159764678, 
  0.0006630728705670156}, {0.07105264041551246, 
  0.0007465819667652495}, {0.06890066952772653, 
  0.0008171453719603333}, {0.0648482568169608, 
  0.000976053119336969}, {0.0639297099358539, 
  0.0010179222593113134}, {0.06342106227146814, 
  0.0010421678651143407}, {0.061574652617965235, 
  0.0011368142898518605}, {0.059100351891575864, 
  0.0012829449507075384}, {0.05827869027987578, 
  0.0013375669973438838}, {0.05578948412742382, 
  0.0015218623255611656}, {0.054423774464439335, 
  0.0016374968051687928}, {0.052420857837279254, 
  0.0018329796165180577}, {0.04990743036747559, 
  0.0021178695173944147}, {0.048157905983379504, 
  0.002355429130050617}, {0.045558772313715974, 
  0.0027773557142080525}, {0.04240441152322109, 
  0.003442245312276653}, {0.04138897937270737, 
  0.0036963942496618823}, {0.04052632783933518, 
  0.003935255900947914}, {0.037409230613996765, 
  0.004997357778414752}, {0.034321944240783525, 
  0.006464366915546581}, {0.03363443146364672, 
  0.006871515294551954}, {0.032894749695290854, 
  0.007340357190916253}, {0.03006458192165723, 
  0.00960980353019457}, {0.029078960623268695, 
  0.010620521351798435}, {0.027826904834011422, 
  0.012139762227223483}, {0.02671831377060655, 
  0.013689720812215192}, {0.025263171551246535, 
  0.016196681390274872}, {0.023599353367010308, 
  0.01987130548360278}, {0.022580194859980952, 
  0.022797874696606883}, {0.020711427067384165, 
  0.029399745399044594}, {0.018960039505030245, 
  0.038365222254596924}, {0.018287432153956024, 
  0.04281328422698936}, {0.018065713941275055, 
  0.04437588266801011}, {0.017631593407202217, 
  0.04774766079357238}, {0.01649878102644564, 
  0.0586706142272511}, {0.015658487632167324, 
  0.06831295475610606}, {0.014859184159561115, 
  0.08040123611056546}, {0.013815804335180057, 
  0.09971036507907274}, {0.01348602178354533, 
  0.1072205750222915}, {0.013113386131980664, 
  0.11676024205927839}, {0.012086774911920015, 
  0.15098955580781592}, {0.010000015263157896, 
  0.2660533148660376}, {0.010000015263157896, 
  0.2835509385911756}, {0.010000015263157896, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.025263171551246535, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.04052632783933518, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.05578948412742382, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.07105264041551246, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.0863157967036011, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.10157895299168973, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.11684210927977837, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.132105265567867, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.14736842185595564, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.16263157814404428, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.1778947344321329, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.19315789072022155, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.20842104700831018, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.22368420329639882, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.23894735958448746, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.2542105158725761, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.2558203018873354, 
  0.9999987396384276}, {0.260569543266527, 
  0.9002500410979579}, {0.2618420940166204, 
  0.8757957440659601}, {0.2640238757565315, 
  0.8351341545160378}, {0.26662114624793726, 
  0.7901362222306625}, {0.26947367216066476, 
  0.7443493438629281}, {0.27036799772442, 
  0.7297218689571064}, {0.2727174655075352, 
  0.6960563689327807}, {0.27423036625288777, 
  0.6751722139909367}, {0.2771052503047091, 
  0.6371246250347038}, {0.27885850104532084, 
  0.6154467319250959}, {0.2842505389234616, 
  0.5543124325647013}, {0.2847368284487534, 
  0.5493035315917327}, {0.2850405265047786, 
  0.5460174363420693}, {0.2863466144635127, 
  0.532494677170081}, {0.28855261752077555, 
  0.5110636800160765}, {0.29126354188590853, 
  0.48606297039886726}, {0.2923684065927977, 
  0.4762180131823315}, {0.29410675190734686, 
  0.4612906069497988}, {0.29751636811916365, 
  0.43375814254337697}, {0.2999999847368421, 
  0.41514964772736146}, {0.2999999847368421, 
  0.2835509385911756}, {0.2999999847368421, 
  0.08040123611056546}, {0.2999999847368421, 
  0.022797874696606883}, {0.2999999847368421, 
  0.006464366915546581}, {0.2999999847368421, 
  0.0018329796165180577}, {0.2999999847368421, 
  0.0005197437457472359}, {0.2999999847368421, 
  0.00014737401267806525}, {0.2999999847368421, 
  0.00007847597621237087}};

data2={{0.026421, 0.880102}, {0.0268178, 0.746742}, {0.0271942, 
  0.634472}, {0.0276739, 0.536112}, {0.0280312, 0.47488}, {0.0287076, 
  0.346523}, {0.0291455, 0.296601}, {0.0295175, 0.253896}, {0.0300024,
   0.215648}, {0.030506, 0.181238}, {0.0312802, 0.139177}, {0.0319591,
   0.119716}, {0.0325865, 0.103702}, {0.0332548, 
  0.0900265}, {0.0339655, 0.0776198}, {0.0344885, 
  0.0720466}, {0.0357332, 0.0539909}, {0.0364653, 
  0.0463016}, {0.0372134, 0.0403451}, {0.0379443, 
  0.035113}, {0.0387223, 0.0304162}, {0.0394182, 
  0.0275844}, {0.0409623, 0.0203708}, {0.0420865, 
  0.0178988}, {0.0437596, 0.0155134}, {0.0453807, 
  0.013276}, {0.047063, 0.0115048}, {0.0485016, 
  0.0112719}, {0.0506136, 0.00833023}, {0.0529264, 
  0.00747158}, {0.0559817, 0.00688619}, {0.0591538, 
  0.00619242}, {0.0645948, 0.0056801}, {0.0626333, 
  0.00566467}, {0.0697434, 0.00456699}, {0.0736612, 
  0.00417951}, {0.0772273, 0.00379961}, {0.0812595, 
  0.00349659}, {0.0856752, 0.00315671}, {0.0889625, 
  0.00310055}, {0.0968806, 0.00250791}, {0.102129, 
  0.00231113}, {0.108357, 0.00218765}, {0.114647, 
  0.00207634}, {0.121303, 0.0019672}, {0.126388, 
  0.0019222}, {0.140037, 0.00170103}, {0.148169, 
  0.00162699}, {0.156771, 0.0015433}, {0.165872, 
  0.00146304}, {0.175501, 0.00138861}, {0.183798, 
  0.00134368}, {0.204696, 0.00118797}, {0.216582, 
  0.00113424}, {0.229153, 0.00107144}, {0.242455, 
  0.00101211}, {0.256528, 0.000956066}, {0.267965, 
  0.000925368}, {0.299199, 0.000814051}, {0.316558, 
  0.000758552}, {0.334914, 0.000694366}, {0.354334, 
  0.000635234}, {0.374881, 0.000582519}, {0.387607, 
  0.000576501}, {0.420909, 0.000451888}, {0.441583, 
  0.000398565}, {0.464751, 0.000346267}, {0.489135, 
  0.000301422}, {0.509853, 0.000278623}, {0.545726, 
  0.000211186}, {0.569648, 0.000185061}, {0.593935, 
  0.000159681}, {0.61827, 0.000137351}, {0.637911, 
  0.000119888}, {0.67462, 0.0000870067}, {0.698866, 
  0.0000749829}, {0.720831, 0.0000640726}, {0.739399, 
  0.0000554034}, {0.762664, 0.0000482517}, {0.805269, 
  0.0000347985}, {0.825927, 0.0000300192}, {0.838617, 
  0.0000258637}, {0.860889, 0.0000222026}, {0.879836, 
  0.0000189785}, {0.886325, 0.0000177987}, {0.919887, 
  0.0000133371}, {0.93044, 0.0000114575}, {0.94442, 
  9.76004*10^-6}, {0.960141, 8.29786*10^-6}, {0.977934, 
  6.98367*10^-6}, {0.967144, 6.4857*10^-6}, {1.00723, 
  4.91017*10^-6}, {1.01476, 4.25439*10^-6}, {1.02665, 
  3.66046*10^-6}, {1.03528, 3.15301*10^-6}, {1.04571, 
  2.73125*10^-6}, {1.05629, 2.43485*10^-6}, {1.07346, 
  1.75992*10^-6}, {1.08666, 1.50936*10^-6}, {1.09757, 
  1.28898*10^-6}, {1.10808, 1.10339*10^-6}, {1.10932, 
  9.40047*10^-7}, {1.11468, 8.59312*10^-7}, {1.12268, 
  6.29552*10^-7}, {1.13343, 5.25539*10^-7}, {1.14154, 
  4.38902*10^-7}, {1.15344, 3.62605*10^-7}, {1.17927, 
  3.16306*10^-7}, {1.20399, 2.032*10^-7}, {1.19695, 
  2.42533*10^-7}, {1.21411, 2.94621*10^-7}, {1.22229, 
  4.40625*10^-7}, {1.22096, 5.31288*10^-7}, {1.22468, 
  7.08256*10^-7}, {1.22694, 8.76305*10^-7}, {1.20904, 
  1.30488*10^-6}, {1.20948, 1.60216*10^-6}, {1.20979, 
  1.84956*10^-6}, {1.2101, 2.13517*10^-6}, {1.21041, 
  2.46487*10^-6}, {1.21114, 3.4547*10^-6}, {1.21155, 
  4.16101*10^-6}, {1.21186, 4.80354*10^-6}, {1.21217, 
  5.5453*10^-6}, {1.20669, 6.84148*10^-6}, {1.20692, 
  8.6485*10^-6}, {1.20884, 0.0000106246}, {1.21093, 
  0.0000131545}, {1.21286, 0.0000162406}, {1.21186, 
  0.0000202058}, {1.21529, 0.0000233107}, {1.20996, 
  0.0000272315}, {1.21282, 0.0000314739}, {1.21313, 
  0.000036334}, {1.21344, 0.0000419446}, {1.21537, 
  0.0000515103}, {1.21748, 0.0000636935}, {1.21779, 
  0.0000735289}, {1.2124, 0.0000840811}, {1.21529, 
  0.0000981186}, {1.2156, 0.00011327}, {1.21592, 
  0.000130761}, {1.21786, 0.000161477}, {1.21998, 
  0.000200909}, {1.2146, 0.000230834}, {1.21748, 
  0.000268798}, {1.2178, 0.000310305}, {1.21811, 
  0.000358222}, {1.22005, 0.000441824}, {1.22218, 
  0.000548959}, {1.21679, 0.000633728}, {1.21968, 
  0.000736378}, {1.21999, 0.000850087}, {1.22031, 
  0.000981356}, {1.22225, 0.00120889}, {1.22438, 
  0.00149996}, {1.21899, 0.00173982}, {1.22188, 0.00201732}, {1.2222, 
  0.00232883}, {1.22251, 0.00268845}, {1.22445, 0.00330769}, {1.22658,
   0.00409847}, {1.2212, 0.00477648}, {1.22409, 0.0055265}, {1.2244, 
  0.00637989}, {1.22472, 0.00736505}, {1.22666, 0.00905029}, {1.22879,
   0.0111986}, {1.2291, 0.0129278}, {1.22366, 0.014748}, {1.22658, 
  0.0172287}, {1.2269, 0.0198891}, {1.22721, 0.0229603}, {1.23332, 
  0.0265346}, {1.231, 0.0305987}, {1.23132, 0.0353237}, {1.22588, 
  0.040489}, {1.22879, 0.0471983}, {1.22911, 0.0544865}, {1.22943, 
  0.0629002}, {1.23139, 0.077628}, {1.23353, 0.0965177}, {1.22809, 
  0.111158}, {1.23101, 0.129301}, {1.23133, 0.149267}, {1.23164, 
  0.172316}, {1.23361, 0.212401}, {1.23575, 0.263723}, {1.23032, 
  0.30517}, {1.23323, 0.354222}, {1.23355, 0.40892}, {1.23387, 
  0.472065}, {1.23583, 0.581157}, {1.23798, 0.720591}, {1.23251, 
  0.82596}, {0.026421, 0.880102}};
```

Comment: That's really the way two translucent objects interact: stack a number of them and the color will darken. This is mentioned in the docs for `Opacity[]`.

Comment: Side note: you don't need to provide the actual (that it tedious to copy paste), instead you can just use five points, or built-in functions to generate dummy data, making it easier to help you without altering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rgn1 = Polygon[{#[[1]], Log10[#[[2]]]} & /@ data1];

rgn2 = Polygon[{#[[1]], Log10[#[[2]]]} & /@ data2];

rgn3 = RegionUnion[rgn1, rgn2];

RegionPlot[rgn3, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "Log10[y]"}]
```

[image]

Or

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[rgn3, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "Log10[y]"}],
 Graphics[{
   Line[{#[[1]], Log10[#[[2]]]} & /@ data1],
   Line[{#[[1]], Log10[#[[2]]]} & /@ data2]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by providing an explicit full `Opacity[1]` in the graphics-styling option of the specified [`Filling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html):

```
ListLogPlot[
 {data1, data2}
 , PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Blue}}
 , Joined -> True
 , Filling -> {
   1 -> {Top, Directive[Lighter[Blue], Opacity[1]]}, 
   2 -> {Top, Directive[Lighter[Blue], Opacity[1]]}
   }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Use a setting with `Opacity[1]` for the option `FillingStyle`:

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, data2}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Filling -> Automatic, FillingStyle -> Opacity[1, LightBlue]]
```

[image]

You can also post-process to change the `FaceForm` of polygons:

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, data2}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue,  Filling -> Automatic] /.
  p_Polygon:> {FaceForm[Opacity[1, LightBlue]], p}
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, data2}, Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[LightBlue, LineColor -> Blue], Filling ->Automatic] /. 
 Opacity[_]:> Opacity[1]
```

> same picture